# Should there be a dead tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed a [dead](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dead) tag that was used to tag a question about leaving a dead fish in an aquarium. Should there actually be a [dead](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dead) tag?

I don't think we need this tag because it is more unlikely for the site to recieve questions about dead animals. I think this question should be tagged [health](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health)

What does the community feel about this?

Comment: For reference: [The question](http://pets.stackexchange.com/q/708/58) in question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I agree that the [dead](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dead) is a bad choice. While I think that this specific question could be tagged with [health](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health), as the health of other fish might be affected, I don't think that it should be a used substitute, but an addition to the current tags used on the question.

We might want to create [death](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/death) regarding the death of pets in general. I guess this would be a better substitution and I feel that it is more in line with tagging guidelines. Topics of [death](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/death) could include how to cope with deaths, funerals, burial etc.